# Using Python With Kivy

Tags: python, debugging, kivy

I got this error after installed and run python code with kivy imported.

my code is like this:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class TestApp(App):
   def build(self):
        return Button(text='Hello World')

TestApp().run()
```

and i got this error:

```
    [INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Fathir Irhas\.kivy\logs\kivy_16-01-17_9.txt
[INFO              ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1
[INFO              ] [Python      ] v3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:43:06) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO              ] [Factory     ] 179 symbols loaded
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "F:\Program\Python\testhelloworld\HelloWorld.py", line 2, in <module>
     from kivy.app import App
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 327, in <module>
     from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 219, in <module>
     from kivy.graphics import (
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\graphics\__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
     from kivy.graphics.instructions import Callback, Canvas, CanvasBase, \
 ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have installed kivy using pip as the kivy document told so, and also
i have put the python path in the environment variables, and i can access python everywhere. My question is how to solve this problem? .Thanks.

Comment: it works now as i try to redownload the depedencies needed.

Answer (score 2):

did you read the installation instructions in the website?
maybe you need to install some modules like pillow, sdl, or the others dependencies for windows

[Kivy - windows install manual](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
pip uninstall kivy
pip install kivy
```